# Should search engine validation meta tags be removed following validation?

Tags: search-engines, validation, meta-tags

Should validation meta tags for search engines be left on the site following validation? For example, should I leave my msvalidate meta tag after I've validated the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's docs on site verification don't mention whether the method of verification used can be removed after successful verification. [1](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35179) [2](http://knol.google.com/k/google-webmaster-tools-verification#)

Neither does [Bing's](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/gg132915.aspx)

The safe thing to do would be to leave them in place but if you feel like figuring this out you can remove them and if you run into any issues, let us know about it here.

Answer (score 7):

All methods should be left in place for Google verification.
Removing them will *un*verify your site. It isn't brought up on the main verification info page, but tacked on to the end of all the detail pages for the methods([meta](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35659), [HTML](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35658), [DNS](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=176792), [GAnalytics](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=185871)), eg:

> Don't delete the tag from the page, as this will cause your site to become unverified.

I don't know about Bing.

Comment: As @Su' said, removing the Google validation snippets/files won't do you any favours, especially any that are used for analytics etc.

Answer (score 4):

I contacted Bing, as I couldn't get a clear reply for Bing. This is what they replied to me:

> Thank you for contacitng Bing Technical Support.  This is (Name removed). 
>   Please allow me to address your issue regarding meta-tag verification.
>   Specifically, you're asking if you should remove the meta-tag after
>   verification.  **Apparently, you shouldn't remove the meta-tag**.  Please
>   be reminded of the things you should note when your site has been
>   verified: .Only verified sites can be used in Bing Webmaster Tools.
>
> .Do not delete the verification code from your site if you want to
>   continue using the Bing Webmaster Tools. Verification is performed
>   every time the tools are accessed and then again approximately every
>   20 minutes or so during your session. Removal of the verification code
>   will prevent Bing Webmaster Tools from verifying your site, and thus
>   deny you access to its tools for that site.
>
> .Bing Webmaster Tools stores the verification permissions in a cookie.
>   Be sure cookies are enabled in your browser
>
> We're hoping that we provided you some clarity on the issue being
>   raised.  If you have further questions or you're referring to
>   different issue, please email us back.