# Can I delete google verification txt file from server?

Tags: google-workspace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validation Meta tags for search engines](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22080/validation-meta-tags-for-search-engines)

I verified ownership of a domain for Google Apps with the text/html file option. Now I need to permanently redirect the domain to another server with .htaccess. Obviously google won't see file anymore.

So I have two options:

1. Do nothing (same as deleting verification code).
2. Move file to new server where htaccess is redirecting to.

Do i really need to drag around that file so my account stays verified? Or is it a one-time process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the file a few times and google asked me to verify again (which is the worst that can happen and is just a minor hassle of getting a new file on the new server).
I would just not move the file to the new server and just get a new one when google asks for it.

Comment: Yes, I think this is what I will do.

Answer (score 7):

From [Google Webmaster Tools](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35658) support:

```
We recommend that you don't delete the file from your server.
```

Better stick with their recommendations since it's a small file and won't cause you any trouble.

Edit:
Some people [there](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/JsHafGi1X2U) say that their Google Apps Email got broken after they deleted their verification file.

Edit 2:
You can also verify by [DNS](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/dns-verification-ftw.html), you won't need that little file on your server then.

Comment: I already did so many changes to DNS of my domain for making mail system work + anti spoofing verification entries... I cannot believe they don't see it and require yet another verification layer :S