# Validation Meta tag for Bing

Tags: bing, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validation Meta tags for search engines](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22080/validation-meta-tags-for-search-engines)

Should validation meta tag for the Bing search engine be left on the site following validation?

Comment: First of all, please don't edit the duplicate text. It's rude to the people who closed the question, and it makes it hard for other users to find the duplicate question. If you disagree with the question being closed, leave a comment instead.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate because every question **does not** get it's own version for different search engines. In addition, bing was covered in the duplicate question. If you feel that the duplicate question is out of date or inaccurate, then leave a comment asking the answerers to update their answers.

Comment: Ok, your arguments are acceptable and I apologize. 
However, you should write those suggestions in FAQ. I looked for this before I post and I didn't find a clue and I didn't know it. You will save a lot of trouble and frustration.

Comment: The FAQ could be a bit clearer, but it really only covers the very basics of how to use the site. If you want more information on Stack Exchange, [Meta.StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) would be a good place to go.